# Linq to XML: Remove duplicate from an item

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file containing things like these:

```
 <item>
  <key>Some text</key>
  <explanation>Some more text</explanation>
  <content language="en-gb">word</content>
  <content language="en">word</content>
</item>
```

I want to see if any of the `<content>` tags with the `language` attribute have the same value and then remove the duplicated field. In this case, for example, there are two `content` tags with a value of `word`. I want to remove one of them.

Comment: Should `language=en` and `language=en-gb` be considered duplicates?

Comment: No, the word following it should be checked for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contents = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Select only elements that have the language attribute
var result = from item in contents.Descendants()
             where item.Attribute("language") != null
             select item;

// Returns only those elements that have at least another element
// with the same value.
var resultDuplicates = result
    .GroupBy(s => s.Value)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));

// If duplicates found, replace them in the original xml.
if (resultDuplicates.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach(var entry in resultDuplicates)
        xml = xml.Replace(entry.ToString(), string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with a simple `LINQ to XML` query:

```
var duplicates = xml.Descendants("content")
        .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Value)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Take(1));

duplicates.Remove();
```

Comment: +1 This works nicely. Though I don't know why you included the last line; it basically removes all the results from the list and not from the XML, as required (that's an easy step though).

Comment: That's incorrect. The `IEnumerable<XElement>` holds references to the original XML nodes. It **will** remove them from the original XML. try it and see :)

Comment: Oook, that's a little bit of a mind twister (in a good way). But still, it removes **all** the `content` nodes, not only one of them.

Comment: @Mihai You're right. I've added `DistinctBy` to make sure only one of the values gets removed.

Comment: It seems possible to avoid `DistinctBy` by taking only the first element from `SelectMany`. Something like: `.SelectMany(g => g.Take(1))`. That would be nicer, I think.

Comment: This didnt work if i had more than one dup. I had to change the last line to `.SelectMany(g => g).Skip(1)`